# htaccess dealing with two variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite an URL with two variables by having two `RewriteRule` for the same page

My original URL looks like `mission.php?id=var123`, the first rule turn this into `planning/var123` with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^planning/([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+)/?$  mission.php?id=$1  [NC,L]
```

This is a simple agenda but I want to be able to remove someone from this agenda by having an URL that should be like `planning/var123/del/user` so I wrote this line

```
RewriteRule ^planning/([A-Za-z0-9-\/]+/del/([A-Za-z0-9-\/-]+)/?$  mission.php?id=$1&del=$2  [NC,L]
```

I tried manually `mission.php?id=var123&del=user` it works, but when I'm trying to open the same page using `planning/var123/del/user` it does not work

I'll be glad if someone could help me

Comment: The pattern of your first rule matches both uris 
`planning/var123` and `planning/var123/del/user`
. Remove the slash that is inside the regex character - class of your first rule `[..........\/]+`

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly, thank you so much!